# SELECT statement not returning correct values when using != (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have two tables, SALES_REP and UNAVAILABLE DATES:

```
import sqlite3
booking = sqlite3.connect('AppointmentBookingSystem.db')

booking.execute('''CREATE TABLE SALES_REP
        (repID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        username TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
        numberOfAppointments INT DEFAULT 0,
        FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES USERNAME_PASSWORD(username));''')

booking.execute('''CREATE TABLE UNAVAILABLE_DATES
        (dateID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        date DATE NOT NULL);''')
```

The relationship between these two tables was many-to-many so I created  a link table with a compound primary key:

```
booking.execute('''CREATE TABLE DATES_REPS
        (dateID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        repID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(dateID, repID),
        FOREIGN KEY (dateID) REFERENCES UNAVAILABLE_DATES(dateID),
        FOREIGN KEY (repID) REFERENCES SALES_REP(repID));''')
```

I am trying to use a SQL select statement to get a list of all the repIDs from SALES_REP which do not exist for the date in the UNAVAILABLE_DATES table

```
date = 2015-09-25
c = booking.cursor()
cursor = c.execute('SELECT SALES_REP.repID FROM SALES_REP, DATES_REPS, UNAVAILABLE_DATES\
    WHERE UNAVAILABLE_DATES.date=? AND UNAVAILABLE_DATES.dateID = DATES_REPS.dateID AND SALES_REP.repID != DATES_REPS.repID', (date,))
IDs = c.fetchall()
```

When I only have 1 record in the DATES_REPS table this is working as expected

```
SALES_REP TABLE
repID
------
  1
  2
  3

UNAVAILABLE_DATES TABLE
dateID  |  date
---------------
   1     2015-09-25

DATES_REPS
dateID  |  repID
-------------------
  1          1
```

which returns:

```
IDs = [(2,), (3,)]
```

However the select statement no longer works correctly after adding another record to the DATES_REPS and UNAVAILABLE_DATES tables

```
SALES_REP TABLE
repID
------
  1
  2
  3

UNAVAILABLE_DATES TABLE
dateID  |  date
---------------
   1     2015-09-25
   2     2015-09-25

DATES_REPS
dateID  |  repID
-------------------
  1          1
  2          2
```

What I'd now expect to get back is '3' but instead I get

```
IDs = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (3,)]
```

And this pattern continues as I add more records to UNAVAILABLE_DATES and DATES_REPS

What I assume is happening is that SALES_REP.repID != DATES_REPS.repID is being returned for each record in the DATES_REPS table (so when 1 is present, 2 and 3 are returned, when 2 is present 1 and 3 are returned etc) rather than the repIDs which are not present in the entire table for this date

Is this to do with the way my tables are joined? Or a problem in my select statement?

Comment: Try this `<>` instead of `!=`

Comment: This returns the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly deduced how SQL evaluates queries.

If you want to check whether some rows do not exist, you should use NOT EXISTS (with a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)):

```sql
SELECT repID
FROM SALES_REP
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM DATES_REPS
                  JOIN UNAVAILABLE_DATES USING (dateID)
                  WHERE UNAVAILABLE_DATES.date = ?
                    AND SALES_REP.repID = DATES_REPS.repID)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `!=` be `=` in `SALES_REP.repID != DATES_REPS.repID` ?

Comment: Just tried this and changed the != to = as @Andomar said, this is working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual to create a many-to-many relation just for a `date`.  Your design could be simpler with just two tables:

```
SalesPerson: ID, Name, ...
SalesPersonUnavailable: SalesPersonID, Date
```

With a primary key on `(SalesPersonID, Date)` for consistency.

Now you can query like:

```
select  name
from    SalesPerson sp
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    SalesPersonUnavailable spu
        where   spu.Date = ?
                and sp.ID = spu.SalesPersonID
        )
```